# PEAR error trying to connect to gandi using test code

Tags: php, api, pear

My first connection attempt to gandi and my script blows up with a mis guided PEAR issue:

```
 # php ganditest.php

PHP Warning:  require_once(XML/RPC2/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/share/pear/XML/RPC2/Client.php on line 43

Warning: require_once(XML/RPC2/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/share/pear/XML/RPC2/Client.php on line 43
    PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'XML/RPC2/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/bin/') in /usr/local/share/pear/XML/RPC2/Client.php on line 43
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'XML/RPC2/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/bin/') in /usr/local/share/pear/XML/RPC2/Client.php on line 43
```

I try to set it to the PEAR dir:

```
# pear config-set bin_dir /usr/local/share/pear
config-set succeeded
```

and

```
# php ganditest.php
PHP Warning:  require_once(XML/RPC2/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/share/pear/XML/RPC2/Client.php on line 43

Warning: require_once(XML/RPC2/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/share/pear/XML/RPC2/Client.php on line 43
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'XML/RPC2/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/bin/') in /usr/local/share/pear/XML/RPC2/Client.php on line 43

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'XML/RPC2/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/bin/') in /usr/local/share/pear/XML/RPC2/Client.php on line 43
```

## cat ganditest.php

```
<?php
require_once '/usr/local/share/pear/XML/RPC2/Client.php';

$version_api = XML_RPC2_Client::create(
    'https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/',
    array( 'prefix' => 'version.', 'sslverify' => True )
);

$apikey = 'mykey';

$result = $version_api->info($apikey);

print_r($result);
?>
```

How do I tell PhP to look for PEAR in the correct folder so I can connect to Gandi?

Comment: you have to fix the include path in your php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just managed to set PEAR to install executable files, ones that you'd execute from the command line, into /usr/local/share/pear which most likely isn't in your $PATH :-)

To answer your question, you need to set the include_path that PHP uses so it can locate the files installed by PEAR.

For example:

```
$ cat a.php 
<?php
echo get_include_path() , "\n";

set_include_path(get_include_path() . ":/usr/local/share/pear");
echo get_include_path() , "\n";
```